# when redirect gives an error "undefined"

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have an odd problem. When I click my button to redirect to a certain controller method it gives me an error "UNDEFINED" but when I refresh the page it gives me the right output.

You can access my site here: http://apps.stratpoint.com:9114/login

Don't know where to debug this kind of problem. Help anyone.

Comment: Your site is dead, dead, dead...

Comment: Something is getting in the way of our output. This might be a PHP error that breaks CI somewhere before it can output something. Also, your site is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One scenario when redirect undefined comes is when the helper class has not been loaded. Make sure you have loaded url helper- this is needed for redirect to work.